# Does in-role cache clear after WebRole reloading?

Tags: asp.net, caching, azure

If I restart WebRole (one exemplar), does InRole cache reload or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. On too many factors.

First of all, let's assume that your Role runs minimum 2 instances to comply with [the SLA](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/).

Now it comes to the [In-Role Cache configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj131263.aspx). And more [on configuration here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh914149.aspx).

If you enabled the High-Availability feature - then copies of all objects are kept on all machines in the cluster. So if a single instance restarts - cache is still there with all objects.

If you didn't enable High-Availability feature - each machine in the cluster keeps only part of the cache. So by instance restart you will loose that part of the cache.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you known answer on that question:

Comment: I have Azure Web Role with ASP.NET WebService. I often make changes and upload package. I need the cache (for example ConcurrentDictionary) in other Windows process at this Web Role, which does not reloading while uploading package with WebService. How I do that?

Comment: with a dedicated Role for caching. or with Caching service, or with Redis Cache ...

Comment: Thank you! I will use Redis Cache.